# Python pandas data frame work, extending a frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a problem with a very huge dataframe. I want to transfer the given record into an empty larger one, because information is missing in the given record. Now I wonder how, I can duplicate this list in a loop and how to take only a new/different number 4000074 in "A" from the given record?

```
base_list =[-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
data = {"A":[4000074 for i in range(28)],
        "B":["SP000796746" for i in range(28)],
        "C":[201824 for i in range(28)],
        "D":[x for x in base_list],}
```

Thank you for help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxXyS.png)

This is the first list out of my code. I want to add further rows, where only one number of A,B,C changes like the next picture show. Only column A
is different for the next 28 rows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7K4j.png)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to create a big list, with nearly 30.000 rows. An the structure should always be A,B,C,D

Comment: But always just one number of A,B,C changes for the next 28 rows. I want to show it in Excel but I do not now how to load up picture here.

Comment: Now I added pictures. So I want to add rows like on the second picture. But very often, so I thought a loop or something like this would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the *permutations* of 4 lists. The simplest way to do that is to use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` and convert the MultiIndex to frame:

```
base_list =[-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    [4000074, 4000075],
    ["SP000796746"],
    [201824],
    base_list,
    [None],
    [None]
], names=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]).to_frame(index=False)
```

Comment: One more question, how can I add two more columns like E,F, but with out any content? So in this columns should be NaN

Comment: You add two lists of `None`s. See my edited answer.